# java.io.FileNotFoundException (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, spring, rest, multipartform-data

I spent my whole day trying to figure out how to solve `java.io.FileNotFoundException (The system cannot find the file specified)` this exception but cant.I test my code with **rest**

```
My controller
@RequestMapping(value = "aboutMe/image", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
                   produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveAboutMe(Author author, @RequestPart("image") MultipartFile authorImage) {
        //Convert Multipart file into BLOB
        try {
            Blob image = Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).createBlob(authorImage.getInputStream(), authorImage.getSize());
            author.setImage(image);
        } catch (HibernateException  | IOException exception) {
            System.out.println((exception.getMessage() + " " +exception));
        }
        authorService.saveAboutMe(author);
        return "saved";
    }
```

my entity

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm")
    @Column(name = "dateOfAuthor")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedTime;

    @Column(name = "aboutMe", length = 10000)
    private String aboutMe;

    @Column(name = "image")
    @Lob
    private Blob image;
```

And I also add multi part form data to `application.properties`.I set folder under **Web-INF**

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true
spring.http.multipart.location=C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.48\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\tmp
```

I test it in rest like this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjWLy.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Here is **stacktrace**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.48\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\tmp\upload_481279d9_9087_48b2_9916_f18292ac14ba_00000000.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getInputStream(DiskFileItem.java:188) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
```

**AuthorService method**

```
public void saveAboutMe(Author author) {
        authorRepository.save(author);
    }
```

Save is Crud function

Comment: When you ask about an exception, always post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: What happens when you configure the multipart location to be *outside* of the deployment path of the root app? And why don't you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: I tried to post but stack gives error saying that question has a lot of code.If you mean that when I set location out of under ` WEB -INF` it gives the same error

Comment: No, I meant out of the webapps directory. Or even out of tomcat. Something like c:\tmp.

Comment: Yes I did it out of tomcat  first, but five me exception.Then i searched google and found out  if i set under  `WEB-INF`  will not give me error.But the result was same .

Comment: Can you put `authorService.saveAboutMe` method??

Comment: @Kenry I put service method

Comment: That entity you show is authorImage?? You don't type the entity name